# cv:Exception at memory location - Running openCV code Visual studio 2013 & Visual studio 2017 - Windows 7

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv

How can I get rid  of Exceptions in Visual Studio? Possibly from project exception settings?

I am using openCV 2.4.9 library with c++ code library in Visual studio. when I run the code. I tried library with 2012 & 2015 also but had "lnk1104" error for missing library file . I tried resolving those with solutions found from internet ( redistributable c++ package & others) but couldn't fix it.

So I tried in 2013 & 2017, but get the unhandled exceptions(Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x0037AD58(& other locations too)) for both versions.

I have been trying to run code successfully since last 3 days.

Can anyone please help me?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) causing the exception. You don't want to get rid of exceptions, you want to avoid them by writing proper code.

Answer (score 0):

exceptions are baked into the code, so you can't rid of them. The best you can do is to use try catch

```cpp
try
{
    my_exception_throwing_function();
}
catch(err)
{

}
```

But in your case I think it's a linker problem. You need to tell the compiler where all the binaries of OpenCV. Check the linker page of the compiler.

Did you recompile OpenCV yourself? Did you use precompiled binaries? if so, were the binaries compiled with the same compiler you are using? Which version of OpenCV are you using?

I would go to the documentations of OpenCV, they have good guides to setup the toolchain.
https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_visual_studio_Opencv/windows_visual_studio_Opencv.html

Comment: Yes It seems to be a linker problem. Have double checked the path to library files.

Comment: Finally I got Visual Studio 2012 working with with library files of OpenCv's "VC10" library folder. Could run my code and get the output too except the Webcam dynamic frame output.